# How do I install Samba 4?

Tags: 10.10, samba

Does anyone have a good installation manual to install samba 4 on ubuntu 10.10.
I found a lot of articles to install samba 4 but all are different and most will not work with my ubuntu version. So some questions has been arised like "Where get I the recent built for ubuntu" and so on.

Answer (score 2):

There is a samba 4 package in Ubuntu's Universe repository. It's currently in the alpha phase, so it's not recommended for critical applications.

You can install it by searching for "samba4" in the Software Center or Synaptic or by typing `sudo apt-get install samba4` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I heard about a daily built on www.launchpad.net which can be used in non productiv environment. The samba4 package from ubuntu is an old built - as I heard.
But there is no complete guide to install and set up an active directory in samba4.

Comment: There is a PPA with daily built packages here: http://launchpad.net/~samba-team/+archive/daily

Answer (score 0):

check out https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/HOWTO. I just installed it on debian after this manual and so far i can connect windows xp and dabian (ther is no linux client howto, but i used a linux-active directory howto and it worked).

To set this up do NOT install kerberos or ldap, it is shipped with the installation in this howto. But you do need to install bind yourself and do the changes described.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend installing samba4 yet as it is an alpha version if you don't have a very good knowledge of samba or a very specific reason not to install samba3... and if so you should know very well how to install and configure it or things will not work very well in your network very soon.